# Magento 2 PWA Setup : Environment has 1 validation errors https://www.pwa-magento.com/ is inactive. Please consider using one of these other backends

Tags: magento2, pwa-studio, venia

> I'm installing PWA Studio on my local and i'm using magento 2.3.3 without sample data but i'm getting error as shown
> in image below. I have followed all the steps for pwa setup but while running this command `yarn run build` and `yarn run watch` It's showing error

```
venia-sample-backends is a "development-only" extension, please remove it from your project's package.json before going to production.

Error: Environment has 1 validation errors: 
 (1) https://www.pwa-magento.com/ is inactive. Please consider using one of these other backends: 

 [{"name":"2.4.1-cloud-meta-package","description":"Magento 2.4.1 with Venia sample data installed","url":"https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/"},{"name":"2.4-develop","description":"Magento 2.4-develop with Venia sample data installed","url":"https://venia-develop-ccewfjy-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/"}]
```

[image: Screenshot]

**I'm using yarn and node versions `yarn version:- 1.22.18` and `node version:- v14.19.1`**

**Let me know if anyone has any solution.**

Comment: did you find any solution for this

Comment: @RanaZain no i guess i don't remember but I might have tried installing again different way

Answer (score 2):

Remove venia-sample-backends package

```
yarn remove @magento/venia-sample-backends
yarn upgrade
```